# How to get map of parameters from custom object

Tags: java

I have class with some of variables.

How I can create map where key will be name of variable and value will be value of this variable ?

So I want to create:

`Map<String, String>` from custom object:

I create something like this:

```
protected Map<String, String> getObjectParams(Object object) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();


        for (String field : (Iterable<String>) BeanUtils.describe(object).keySet()) {
            Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, field);
            if ((value != null) && (!"CLASS".equalsIgnoreCase(field)) {                     
                result.put(field, value.toString());
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

but this will works only when class contains primitive objects and their wrapped equivalent. But when there will be another custom object with generated toString then there will value which I dont want. So how should I rewrite this example ?

UPDATE:

```
public Class MyCustomClass1 {


  MyCustomClass2 customClass2;
}

public Class MyCustomClass2 {

  String a;
  String b;
}
```

then map should contains value MyCustomClass2A and MyCustomClass2B and their values or something similar

Comment: What do you expect the 'value' of an object to be, other than its ``toString`` method?

Comment: I expect toString value just of primite object and their wrapped equivalent. When it isnt primitive object then there should be some prefix. More in update

Comment: Are you trying to make a full description of an object such as what a debugger could do eg : { "customClass2.a" : "a", "customClass2.b" : "b"} ?

Comment: yes something similar but I want to save this in Map

Comment: toMap() function of which class ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to overload toString() method in your custom classes to get desired value. Something like :

```
public Class MyCustomClass1 {
  MyCustomClass2 customClass2;
  public String toString(){
      return customClass2.toString();
  }
}

public Class MyCustomClass2 {

  String a;
  String b;
  public String toString(){
          return a  + " " + b;
      }
}
```

This is just an example, change toString() as required.

Or use this [how-to-get-the-list-of-all-attributes-of-a-java-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038308/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-attributes-of-a-java-object-using-beanutils-introspec)

Comment: In our application we already had custom toString methods which I cant override and also this doesnt help me because then in map will be key MyCustomClass2 and in value will be 2 values from this class which is wrong

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038308/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-attributes-of-a-java-object-using-beanutils-introspec)

Comment: sorry but I dont understand how this link should helps me. It return string of class in really different format

Answer (score 0):

Update return type to Map or Map
and use recursion to populate child objects.